# How to check dates condition from one table to another in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

Which way we can use to check and compare the dates from one table to another.

**Table : inc**

```
+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| inc_id | cust_id |  item_id  | serv_time |  inc_date   |
+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|      1 | john    | HP        |        40 | 17-Apr-2015 |
|      2 | John    | HP        |        60 | 10-Jan-2016 |
|      3 | Nick    | Cisco     |       120 | 11-Jan-2016 |
|      4 | samanta | EMC       |       180 | 12-Jan-2016 |
|      5 | Kerlee  | Oracle    |        40 | 13-Jan-2016 |
|      6 | Amir    | Microsoft |       300 | 14-Jan-2016 |
|      7 | John    | HP        |       120 | 15-Jan-2016 |
|      8 | samanta | EMC       |        20 | 16-Jan-2016 |
|      9 | Kerlee  | Oracle    |        10 | 2-Feb-2017  |
+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

**Table: Contract:**

```
+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
|  item_id  | con_id  |  Start   |    End     |
+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
| Dell      | DE2015  | 1/1/2015 | 12/31/2015 |
| HP        | HP2015  | 1/1/2015 | 12/31/2015 |
| Cisco     | CIS2016 | 1/1/2016 | 12/31/2016 |
| EMC       | EMC2016 | 1/1/2016 | 12/31/2016 |
| HP        | HP2016  | 1/1/2016 | 12/31/2016 |
| Oracle    | OR2016  | 1/1/2016 | 12/31/2016 |
| Microsoft | MS2016  | 1/1/2016 | 12/31/2016 |
| Microsoft | MS2017  | 1/1/2017 | 12/31/2017 |
+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
```

**Result:**

```
+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
| Calls | Cust_id | Con_id  | Tot_Ser_Time |
+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
|     2 | John    | HP2016  |          180 |
|     2 | samanta | EMC2016 |          200 |
|     1 | Nick    | CIS2016 |          120 |
|     1 | Amir    | MS2016  |          300 |
|     1 | Oracle  | OR2016  |           40 |
+-------+---------+---------+--------------+
```

MY Query:

```
select count(inc_id) as Calls,  inc.cust_id,  contract.con_id,
  sum(inc.serv_time) as tot_serv_time
from  inc inner join contract   on inc.item_id = contract.item_id  
where  inc.inc_date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
group by inc.cust_id,  contract.con_id
```

The result from inc table with filter between 1-jan-2016 to 31-Dec-2016 with 
count of inc_id based on the items and its contract start and end dates .

Comment: please explain how you should arrive at the result.

Comment: Your question is a little vague, but I think you are looking for the between keyword  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx

Comment: @vkp i tried to get result from inc table with condition, inc_dates between 1-jan-2016 to 31-Dec-2016 and count of inc_id based on the item_id which is having contract with start and end dates

Comment: @mjhouseman : sorry to explain my question. basically i am trying to get the inc_id counts group by contract per customer between the dates 1-1-2016 to 12-31-2016.  the date should check from contract table start and end dates

Comment: @Salman What does your current query look like? It's easier for us to nudge you in the right direction if we know where you currently are

Comment: @mjhouseman: i added my query, i am facing issue while compare the start and end with inc_date...

Comment: @Salman the problem with your query is that you need to filter the join based on the dates of the contract as well. For example, you will get two results back for Amir, 1 for 2016 and 1 for 2017 with your query

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem, this query will return the desidered result:

```
select
  count(*) as Calls,
  inc.cust_id,
  contract.con_id,
  sum(inc.serv_time) as tot_serv_time
from
  inc inner join contract
  on inc.item_id = contract.item_id
     and inc.inc_date between contract.start and contract.end
where
  inc.inc_date between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
group by
  inc.cust_id,
  contract.con_id
```

the question is a little vague so you might need some adjustments to this query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    Calls = count(*)
  , Cust = i.Cust_id
  , Contract = c.con_id
  , Serv_Time = sum(Serv_Time)
from inc as i
  inner join contract as c
    on i.item_id = c.item_id
    and i.inc_date >= c.[start]
    and i.inc_date <= c.[end]
where c.[start]>='20160101'
group by i.Cust_id, c.con_id 
order by i.Cust_Id, c.con_id
```

returns:

```
+-------+---------+----------+-----------+
| Calls |  Cust   | Contract | Serv_Time |
+-------+---------+----------+-----------+
|     1 | Amir    | MS2016   |       300 |
|     2 | John    | HP2016   |       180 |
|     1 | Kerlee  | OR2016   |        40 |
|     1 | Nick    | CIS2016  |       120 |
|     2 | samanta | EMC2016  |       200 |
+-------+---------+----------+-----------+
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/WSYDL43321

```
create table inc(
    inc_id int
  , cust_id varchar(16)
  , item_id varchar(16)
  , serv_time int
  , inc_date  date
 );
insert into inc values
 (1,'john','HP', 40 ,'17-Apr-2015')
,(2,'John','HP', 60 ,'10-Jan-2016')
,(3,'Nick','Cisco', 120 ,'11-Jan-2016')
,(4,'samanta','EMC', 180 ,'12-Jan-2016')
,(5,'Kerlee','Oracle', 40 ,'13-Jan-2016')
,(6,'Amir','Microsoft', 300 ,'14-Jan-2016')
,(7,'John','HP', 120 ,'15-Jan-2016')
,(8,'samanta','EMC', 20 ,'16-Jan-2016')
,(9,'Kerlee','Oracle', 10 ,'02-Feb-2017');

create table contract (
    item_id varchar(16) 
  , con_id varchar(16)
  , [Start] date
  , [End] date
);
insert into contract values 
 ('Dell','DE2015','20150101','20151231')
,('HP','HP2015','20150101','20151231')
,('Cisco','CIS2016','20160101','20161231')
,('EMC','EMC2016','20160101','20161231')
,('HP','HP2016','20160101','20161231')
,('Oracle','OR2016','20160101','20161231')
,('Microsoft','MS2016','20160101','20161231')
,('Microsoft','MS2017','20170101','20171231');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution,  Seems to be this suitable solution

Comment: :Thanks again, if i have some inc_id with item and it has no related info in contract table, in this case i need to keep NULL or blank in contract filed . How i can accomplish this ?